# GWT Cross Project Integration

Tags: gwt

I have two GWT Web Application: A and B.

There is a X view inside A, and inside B there is a Y view.

I want to do two kind of things:

1-. Embed the Y view inside X view.

2-. Go to Y view from the X view.

What is the best way to this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add A.jar in project B and B.jar in project A. Also in A.gwt.xml inherit project B and in B.gwt.xml inherit project B. I am working in this approach in my current project.